# ignore search field if key not present in find() of mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

i want to search using these fields,

`{ "tag":"tag2", "date":"2022-07-18", "userId":"1", "postId":"12" }`

and if some fields are empty (suppose tag:" "), then the search result should be based on other fields that have some key, if all fields are empty then the result will show all data.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `$and` and `$or`. For example:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {$or: [{tag: "tag2"}, {tag: " "}]},
    {$or: [{userId: "1"}, {userId: " "}]},
    {$or: [{postId: "12"}, {postId: " "}]}
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A4NzdurjKGE)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there any chance to get all documents like `db.collection.find()` if all search keys are ""( empty), or i should make conditional for all keys are ""?

Comment: If the input is empty or if there are documents with an empty value for this field?

Comment: I initially ensured that these fields will **never** be empty in documents.